# How to get value from array when input range has particular value using React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to set different number using useState hook and input with type "range".
Let's say I have an array of values:

```
const arr = [{range:1, number:10},{range:2, number:50}, {range:3, number:100}]
```

And input:

```
<Input
  value={value.range}
  onChange={handleChangeValue}
  type="range"
  min="1"
  max="3">
</Input>
```

I want to display number when my slider have particular range, for example when range is 2 I want number 50:

```
<h1>{value.number}</h1>
```

How can I do this using useState hook? Because I know that hooks cannot be used in if statements.

Please advise :)

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(arr[2])

 function handleChangeValue() {
       
    }
```

Comment: try function handleChangeValue(e) { setValue(arr.find(item => item.range = e.target.value)); }

Comment: Number is changing to 10 and then I can't change range in my slider.

Answer (score 1):

Manage to write function myself :)

This one works for  me:

```
    function handleChangeValue(e) {
        setValue(arr[e.target.value-1])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Input
  value={value.range}
  onChange={handleChangeValue}
  type="range"
  min="1"
  max="3">
</Input>
```

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(arr[2])

function handleChangeValue(e) {
    
    const selected = arr.find((obj) => obj.range === e.target.value)
    selected && setValue(selected)
       
}
```

Comment: you don't need to use (e) => handleChangeValue(e). Just use onChange={handleChangeValue}

Comment: some exception handling: selected && setValue(selected)

Comment: @TopW3 you're right . I've updated my answer

Comment: Now I can't change range on my slider. It just doesn't move.

Comment: Can you edit your question with more details?